# Large Collada meshes only render partially

Tags: mesh, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ever since I've upgraded to Gazebo 7, any LARGE mesh I use as a visual in a model file only partially loads.  The majority of the polygons/shapes are missing when I load the model in Gazebo.  I have opened the Collada files in other software and verified that the meshes are correct.  Any ideas what might be causing the issue?  These meshes used to work fine in previous versions of Gazebo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14593/large-collada-meshes-only-render-partially/) by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 207 on 2016-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the answer:

It turns out that Google SketchUp screws up the orientation of surface normals when exporting Collada (dae) meshes.  What I have to do is export a SketchUp file as an OBJECT (obj) file, and then import the obj file into MeshLab.  I then export as a Collada (dae) file from MeshLab, since MeshLab makes sure the orientation of the surface normals is done correctly.  The mesh then loads fine in Gazebo.

The weird thing is that I've been using the same model for years now.  It hasn't been until the last 2 or 3 versions of Gazebo that I noticed the model's mesh stopped loading properly.  Maybe something changed with ogre?

---

Originally posted by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) with karma: 207 on 2016-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0